# Custom Google Dataflow Options

Tags: java, spring-mvc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Due to very small traffic expected, dataflow with minimum resources is needed.
The values needed are: 1`vCPU`, 1`GB` `Memory` and 30`GB` `Storage - Standard Persistent Disk`.

How can one create such a dataflow? What i have so far is the following:

```
    DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
    options.setProject("project-id");
    options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
    //Begin: Autoscalling --disable
    options.setAutoscalingAlgorithm(DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.AutoscalingAlgorithmType.NONE);
    options.setNumWorkers(1);
    //End: Autoscalling
    options.setStreaming(true);
    options.setAppName("");
    options.setMaxNumWorkers(1);
```

Where can one specify resources like `vCPU`, `Memory` and `Storage - Standard Persistent Disk` in dataflow options?

## Update

I'm new to `GCP`, any criticism is accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Javadocs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.4.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.AutoscalingAlgorithmType.html)

> **setDiskSizeGb**
>
> Remote worker disk size, in gigabytes, or 0 to use the default size.

And ...

> **setWorkerMachineType**
>
> Machine type to create Dataflow worker VMs as.
>
> See [GCE machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) for a list of valid options.
>
> If unset, the Dataflow service will choose a reasonable default.

The allowed machine types are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types), for your needs ("1vCPU, 1GB Memory") this one is the closest match: `n1-standard-1`.

So, if you invoke the following methods on `DataflowPipelineOptions` ...

```
options.setDiskSizeGb(30);
options.setWorkerMachineType("n1-standard-1");
```

... then your dataflow workers will run on VM's with 1 CPU and 3.75GB of memory and they will use a storage disk of 30GB.